# XmlIgnore ONLY in Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xmlignore

```
        private string _password;

        public string Password
        {
            get 
            {
                return _password; 
            }
            set
            {
                if (_password != value)
                {
                    _password = PasswordEncryptor.Encode(value);
                    OnPropChanged("Password");                
                }
            }
        }
```

`PasswordEncryptor` is a class where I call the `Encode` method to encode. And after the `Password` is encoded, it is serialized by `XmlSerializer` to a file in disk. However, every time when the program starts, the file is deserialized, and in `set`, `PasswordEncryptor.Encode()` encodes the `Password` again. Is there a way I can `[XmlIgnore]` it ONLY in deserialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlAttributeOverrides` can help in this scenario.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Allows you to override property, field, and class attributes when you
>   use the XmlSerializer to serialize or deserialize an object

Using this we can make a particular property to be ignored during deserialization.

It will be something like this...

```
XmlElementAttribute attr = new XmlElementAttribute();
attr.ElementName = "<elementName>";

XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();
attrs.XmlIgnore = true;
attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);

XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
attrOverrides.Add(typeof(<className>), "<elementName>", attrs);

// use this when deserializing
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(<className>), attrOverrides);

// use this when serializing
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(<className>));
```

Comment: But the XmlSerializer I am using also serialize many other properties, and all the other properties need to be both serialized or deserialized. How can I single this Password property out?

Comment: Just use different XmlSerializer for serializing and deserializing. If you want all properties including the password property to be serialized, just use the XmlSerializer without any overrides and do not specify XmlIgnore on the password property. For deserializing, use the XmlSerializer with overrides as above. Include the password element and set XmlIgnore attribute as overrides.

Comment: Yea, I want all properties to be serialized together so I don't get two files. The second one is a really good idea! Do I need to mark something above the Password property? Something like [XmlIgnore] except not in this case?

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, you don't need to set anything on the password property as you will explicitly set this to ignore when you override.

Comment: I just tried it; it sort of works but not entirely. The property in the file saved to disk will be ignored during deserialization, but it still goes into the set inside property and encodes the already encoded password again.

Comment: I'll have to try that out. But as a workaround, try using a boolean property in your object and set a value for it before deserialize and use that boolean property inside your Password Set method `if` condition to avoid encoding again.